# Triple boot ubuntu with Windows 10 and Windows 7 BCD error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had a dual boot configuration with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 and GRUB booting in the UEFI mode. I wanted to install Windows 7 and made a bootable USB drive. I tried to boot into the drive in UEFI mode, but it didn't work so then I tried Legacy and it loaded the setup, but it encountered a driver problem and it wouldn't show the partitions. After that I started Windows 10 and opened the setup from there and the Windows 7 installation seemed to work fine until I had to restart the computer. After restart I selected the "Windows boot manager" option from GRUB and I had to choose between Windows setup and Windows 10. I chose Windows setup and then it got stuck on the "Starting Windows" screen. I manually restarted the computer, tried it again but I got the same result. The third I actually got a boot error, saying that "Your PC Device need to be repaired" and that it was a problem with the boot files. I didn't even get to the Windows choosing screen this time.

Is there anything I can do now without losing all the files on Windows 10? If not, how should I approach the installation of both Windows 10 and Windows 7 while keeping Ubuntu intact? Thank you!

Comment: If you had UEFI, then drive was gpt. And Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt and only in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode from MBR. If you forced a BIOS/MBR install of Windows 7, you converted drive to MBR. Then neither Windows 10 nor Ubuntu will work. If you converted Windows 7 DVD to flash drive and made the UEFI modifications it should have installed. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I am actually writing this from Ubuntu,  it looks like it has not been affected. Here is the link : http://paste2.org/YBeIhmab

Comment: I know you can convert a Windows 7 DVD to UEFI boot from flash drive by moving files to make it UEFI. But do not know details nor how to install it in UEFI mode with an existing UEFI Windows. Best on a Windows forum.